# PHP - page redirection when refreshed

Tags: php

Is it possible to redirect the user to the start page of my site (it's written using PHP), when the user decides to refresh the site's page?

I'm new to PHP and haven't been able to figure it out on my own so far.

So, if it is possible, how should I do it?

Comment: yes it is, in sorts; use an input with a form and a header, all set in a conditional statement. I'd of popped an answer with an example, but gave it a second thought since that may not be what you had in mind, and stands to have too many possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

try using header("Location:your_site_url_here"); for redirection ...

Answer (score 0):

header('Location:your_url_here '); //Use something like this